# Unexpected cyclic dependency while combining spring-kafka and reactor-kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, project-reactor, circular-reference

The following code produces unexpected cyclic dependency between receiverOptions and template:

Surprisingly it works if kafkaProps are removed from spring context.

Looks like some auto-configuration is adding an unnecessary dependency from template to the receiverOptions.

Please suggest a proper way to configure ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> kafkaProps() {
        return Map.of(
            ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092",
            ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, DemoApplication.class.getSimpleName()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions(Map<String, Object> kafkaProps) {
        return ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(kafkaProps)
            .withKeyDeserializer(new StringDeserializer())
            .withValueDeserializer(new StringDeserializer())
            .subscription(List.of("test-topic"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String> template(ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions) {
        return new ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<>(receiverOptions);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate<String, String> kafkaReceiver) {
        return args -> kafkaReceiver.receive()
            .log()
            .subscribe();
    }
}
```

Full project can be found at https://github.com/piddubnyi/spring-reactor-kafka-ciclyc

Full stacktrace:

```
2020-01-07 16:29:51.031 DEBUG 24915 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'receiverOptions': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:339) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:215) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1503) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1467) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1386) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1245) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:19) ~[main/:na]
```

Comment: Any chances to see a stack trace?

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose Spring doesn't know which `Map<String, Object>` to inject. Try to add `@Qualifier("kafkaProps")` to the `kafkaProps` parameter:

```java
@Bean
public ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions(@Qualifier("kafkaProps") Map<String, Object> kafkaProps) {
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Strange thing, after adding `@Qualifier` Spring wraps `kafkaProps` in another map...

For now, maybe just use a Properties instead of a Map:

```java
@Bean
public Properties kafkaProps() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, DemoApplication.class.getSimpleName());
    return props;
}

@Bean
public ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions(@Qualifier("kafkaProps") Properties kafkaProps) {
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Regarding strange `Map<String, Object>` injection: actually it is not that strange.
`Map<String, SomeType>`, when injected by type, is treated in a special way:
it collects all the beans of the type `MyType` (the keys are beans names).
So in your case, `Map<String, Object>` is a map of all the beans in the context, which obviously
ends up with a circular reference. The same thing would happen for a `List<Object>` or a `Set<Object>`.
Adding @Qualifier annotation doesn't change this behavior, but filters the beans.
Thus the `kafkaProps` map is the only bean passing through the filter and it seems to
be 'wrapped' in another map.

> Even typed Map instances can be autowired as long as the expected key type is String. The map values contain all beans of the expected type, and the keys contain the corresponding bean names (...)

Switching to injection by name should solve the problem. Normally it would be done by adding `@Resource(name = "kafkaProps")` instead of (implicit) `@Autowired` annotation but unfortunately,
the `@Resource` annotation cannot be put on a method parameter.

There is another solution though. As both beans are declared in the same `@Configuration` class,
you can call `kafkaProps()` directly. 
Spring will return the same bean,
not a new instance on each call (caution, it does not hold for static methods)

```java
@Bean
public ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions() {
    return ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(kafkaProps())
        ...
}
```

References:

- [Using @Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation)
- [Further Information About How Java-based Configuration Works Internally](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-further-information-java-config)

Comment: I think this is right observation. The `Map<String, Object>` injection is really about the whole `BeanFactory.getBeansOfType()`.

Comment: Yep, it worked. I'm marking this as the right answer.

Comment: @IgorPiddubnyi Not really, Springs wraps `kafkaProps` in another Map for some reason...

Comment: yep, I also faced a problem of absent bootstrap servers, however, I thought there is something wrong with my config. Now after some debugging, I see following params being passed to the actual KafkaConsumer:

"kafkaSettings" -> {ImmutableCollections$MapN@3369}  size = 2
 key = "kafkaSettings"
 value = {ImmutableCollections$MapN@3369}  size = 2
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "0.0.0.0:9092"
  "group.id" -> "DemoApplication"
"enable.auto.commit" -> "false"

I think there is unnecessary wrapping with kafkaSettings there,

Comment: Yep, using only properties works for now.
Not sure if this problem deserves a GitHub issue to reactor-kafka.

Comment: I don't think it's related to reactor-kafka, rather to injecting maps in general

Comment: Confirmed, found that the problem is reproducible only with a generics <String, Object>, as long as I use a raw map - it works without a problem.
Really strange feature of spring injection.